# maxMemory and outOfMemoryException

Tags: android, facebook, heap-memory

I developed an App for android. My Problem is that the App crashes on a Huawei Honor 7 but works fine on Samsung Galaxy S3 mini, Galaxy S4, Galaxy S6, Nexus 4 and Nexus 5.

I set this line in the application tag in the manifest:

```
android:largeHeap="true"
```

But this error is in the logcat of the Huawei:

```
Throwing OutOfMemoryError "Failed to allocate a 31806012 byte allocation with 4194304 free bytes and 24MB until OOM"
```

I test the maxMemory on my S4 and on the Huawei and get this values:
Galaxy S4: 192MB
Huawei Honor 7: 256MB

To get the values, i use this code:

```
    Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
    long maxMemory = rt.maxMemory();
    Log.v("onCreate", "maxMemory:" + Long.toString(maxMemory));
```

I wonder what this values mean. Because the error above says that there only are ca 4MB on the Device.

My 2 questions now are the following:

1. What does the maxMemory stand for? And what does the ca 4MB from the error stand for?
2. How do Apps like Facebook view so many images? i can scroll and scroll and scroll and then there are 300 images load in the app. But in my app i only can show a few images until it crashes?

Thank you!

Comment: check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34674539/throwing-outofmemoryerror-on-huawei-honor-7

Comment: and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34676621/app-crashes-on-huawei-honor-7

Comment: this does not answer the two questions :/

Comment: sorry, please also use `leakCanary` library to find why memory is leaked

Comment: i tried leakCanary and it tells me, that my mainform was leaked. but i do not really get what to do with this information

Comment: ask on leakCanary GitHub page

Answer (score 0):

31806012 byte = 31.806012 mb
4194304  byte = 4.194304 mb

1)from what i understand the app required memory is 31mb 
but the device have only 4mb in current remaining 24+ memory 
is out of memory so it crash.

2)facebook find the solution for scrolling fast and load more image by following

a) Reducing Garbage Collection

b) Writing a Custom Event Bus

c) Moving Photos to the Native Heap

d) Writing a Custom ListView Recycler

[for more details see the link](https://www.facebook.com/notes/facebook-engineering/under-the-hood-rebuilding-facebook-for-android/10151189598933920)

hope its helpful.

Comment: okay thank you. but what is mp? you mean mb?  and what does the 24 mean? 31 - 4 != 24

Comment: sorry its my mistake its mb not mp , 24 mb is needed to process